# Magento catalog category flat index refresh Enterprise 1.13+

Tags: magento, indexing, refresh, categories, flat

Not a question more of a information.

Data leek happens on the category refresh of flat table rows.

Bug reproducing steps:

- create more then 1 category
- set a attribute like "Default Product Listing Sort By" to a non default value for one of the categories and save it
- full reindex
- set index on manual
- re-arrange the categories and run the enterprise reindex all cronjob

check in the flat table and see that the attribute is copied to all categories that have a position after the category that contains the attribute.

The data leek happens because the Loading of categories is done without the reset of the previous values loaded.

in the file:
Enterprise\Catalog\Model\Index\Action\Category\Flat\Refresh.php

search for _reindex function(line 828)

you will see the model being loaded by `$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');`

The fix is reseting the $category variable on each loop of the   `foreach ($categoriesIdsChunk as $categoryId) {` before the load of the new category.

Simple fix:

```
foreach ($categoriesIdsChunk as $categoryId) {
    if (!isset($attributesData[$categoryId])) {
        continue;
    }
    //add this line to reset the category data.
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');

    if ($category->load($categoryId)->getId()) {
        $data[] = $this->_prepareValuesToInsert(
            array_merge(
                $category->getData(),
                $attributesData[$categoryId],
                array('store_id' => $store->getId())
            )
        );
    }
 }
```

Comment: This bug exists in EE 1.14.1 as well.  Thanks for the fix here Alex.

Comment: Just a comment on fixing this.  You might find yourself scratching your head a little bit because if you put in a rewrite to handle the fix mentioned above, it won't work.  You also need to rewrite Enterprise\Catalog\Model\Index\Action\Category\Flat\Refresh\Row.php and Enterprise\Catalog\Model\Index\Action\Category\Flat\Refresh\Changelog.php as they extend Enterprise\Catalog\Model\Index\Action\Category\Flat\Refresh.php.

Comment: "Data leek" sounds yummy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm going to elaborate a bit on this topic because it's important but the original topic / answer is a bit incomplete (as of Enterprise 1.14.1).

Simply rewriting `a/c/c/E/Catalog/Model/Index/Action/Category/Flat/Refresh.php` is only half the solution.  During the drag and drop reordering of categories, there are calls to the following code in observers that watch for category save and move events...

```
public function processCategorySaveEvent(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    if ($this->_isLiveCategoryReindexEnabled()) {
        // ...
        $client->execute('enterprise_catalog/index_action_category_flat_refresh_row', $arguments);
    }
}

public function processCategoryMoveEvent(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    if ($this->_isLiveCategoryReindexEnabled()) {
        // ...
        $client->execute('enterprise_catalog/index_action_category_flat_refresh_changelog');
    }
};
```

Unfortunately, `enterprise_catalog/index_action_category_flat_refresh_row` and `enterprise_catalog/index_action_category_flat_refresh_changelog` directly extend `a/c/c/E/Catalog/Model/Index/Action/Category/Flat/Refresh.php` and, therefore, need to be rewritten as well.

In the end, the final fix looks something more like this...

`a/c/local/Namespace/Modulename/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <modulename>
                <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model</class>
            </modulename>
            <!-- Enterprise_Catalog_Model_Index_Action_Category_Flat_Refresh_Row -->
            <!-- Enterprise_Catalog_Model_Index_Action_Category_Flat_Refresh_Changelog -->
            <!-- Enterprise_Catalog_Model_Index_Action_Category_Flat_Refresh -->
            <enterprise_catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <index_action_category_flat_refresh_row>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Catalog_Index_Action_Category_Flat_Refresh_Row</index_action_category_flat_refresh_row>
                    <index_action_category_flat_refresh_changelog>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Catalog_Index_Action_Category_Flat_Refresh_Changelog</index_action_category_flat_refresh_changelog>
                    <index_action_category_flat_refresh>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Catalog_Index_Action_Category_Flat_Refresh</index_action_category_flat_refresh>
                </rewrite>
            </enterprise_catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

`a/c/local/Namespace/Modulename/Model/Catalog/Index/Action/Category/Flat/Refresh/Row.php`

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Catalog_Index_Action_Category_Flat_Refresh_Row extends Namespace_Module_Model_Catalog_Index_Action_Category_Flat_Refresh
{
    protected $_keyColumnIdValue;

    public function __construct(array $args)
    {
        parent::__construct($args);
        if (isset($args['value'])) {
            $this->_keyColumnIdValue = $args['value'];
        }
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->_isFlatIndexerEnabled()) {
            return $this;
        }
        $this->_validate();
        $this->_reindex(array($this->_keyColumnIdValue));
        return $this;
    }
}
```

`a/c/local/Namespace/Modulename/Model/Catalog/Index/Action/Category/Flat/Refresh/Changelog.php`

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Catalog_Index_Action_Category_Flat_Refresh_CHangelog extends Namespace_Module_Model_Catalog_Index_Action_Category_Flat_Refresh
{
    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->_isFlatIndexerEnabled()) {
            return $this;
        }
        $this->_validate();
        $changedIds = $this->_selectChangedIds();
        if (is_array($changedIds) && count($changedIds) > 0) {
            $idsBatches = array_chunk($changedIds, Mage::helper('enterprise_index')->getBatchSize());
            foreach ($idsBatches as $changedIds) {
                $this->_reindex($changedIds);
            }
            $this->_setChangelogValid();
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

`a/c/local/Namespace/Modulename/Model/Catalog/Index/Action/Category/Flat/Refresh.php`

```
foreach ($categoriesIdsChunk as $categoryId) {
    if (!isset($attributesData[$categoryId])) {
        continue;
    }

    // Flat Reindexing Fix
    // Flat Reindexing Fix
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
    // Flat Reindexing Fix
    // Flat Reindexing Fix

    if ($category->load($categoryId)->getId()) {
        $data[] = $this->_prepareValuesToInsert(
            array_merge(
                $category->getData(),
                $attributesData[$categoryId],
                array('store_id' => $store->getId())
            )
        );
    }
}
```

I feel like there might be a better way to accomplish this that's less invasive but it does work.  Just be aware of this code when you're updating as it'll probably need to be attended to.